# Extract data.table as vector in case of many columns

Tags: r, data.table

supposed we have

```
dt <- data.table(x = 5, y = 4, z = 6)
```

If we want the return to be a vector,`[1] 5 4 6`, we use `dt[,c(x, y, z)]`.

How should I write the code if there are many columns?

Comment: Just `names(dt)` or `dt[,names(dt)]`

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel the next function that I have to use require the input as a vector.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Are you trying to split your datatable into separate rows?

Comment: Probably you want a matrix, not a data.table, if all your cols are numeric and you habitually grab rows to pass to functions.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to return a vector of the columnnames, you can use the following options:

```
names(dt)
```

or

```
colnames(dt)
```

or

```
dt[,names(dt)]
```

If you want to return the first row, you can just use:

```
unlist(dt[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return the first row as vector, you can simply do:

```
unlist(dt[1,])
#x y z 
#5 4 6
```